# Stuck outer bearing race in motorcycle wheel?

Tags: motorcycle, wheel-bearing

I have the outer race of a bearing stuck in my wheel. I'm out of ideas to get it out, I have tried griding down to relieve the tension and let it pop out with no luck.
I have used a tonne of heat also to no avail.
I don't have access to a welder unfortunatley.
I think there is a tonne of corrosion in there, that's all I can think of, I have a blind bearing puller on the way which is big enough for this size although I don't know if it will fit under the bearing yet.
Any ideas on other ways that could get this out?
Cheers

[image]
[image]

Comment: I once removed a stuck front wheel bearing race by heating a section red hot and quickly quenching. It changed the temper of that section of the race into a brittle state so a blow with a ball peen shattered it. Removal of the entire race was easy after that. BTW, if you're trying to remove with heat, you should be heating the surrounding metal not the race itself. The surrounding metal will have a greater thermal expansion rate than the bearing race.

Comment: @Jeeped when you quenched, did you do the race itself? I have been heating the hub itself(it's aluminium). I use a heat gun as I don't have a blow torch. I have heated to the point the paint is bubbling and cracking/peeling( I'm not too fussed as the wheel needs re-painting ha). The highest setting I use on the gun is 650 deg C.

Comment: Yes, the second part of my comment may have made the first part confusing. If you are trying to make the race brittle, heat up a section of the race at least cherry red then thoroughly and quickly quench. The faster you can dissipate the heat the more you will chenge the temper. The second part of my comment was directed to your current practice of using heat to 'loosen' and remove the race.

Comment: I see, so if I was to heat a part of the race until it glows and then pour cold water over it I should be able to shatter it?Would this not compromise the ally hub in any way? I'm not fussed how I get it out as long as I can get a new bearing in there. Cheers

Comment: That's the method I used with success. Your own success will depend on many factors that I am not privy to. Heat as quick as possible then quench quickly and thoroughly. If done correctly, the sudden changes in internal stresses may even crack the race during the quench.

Comment: Cheers, I'll give it a shot although I don't think the heat gun would be fast enough.

Comment: No, not a heat gun but a hand held propane torch commonly used for soldering pipes should be sufficient

Comment: I use a mig welder, do a couple of tack welds in the center of the race, this will cause it to crack, which makes it much easier to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Given the state of that then I would grind the other side and use a big chisel and matching hammer to crack the last bit -  always worked in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it out, Sorry for the late update.
Used a dremel with a better grinding tip and diamond disc. With a bit more patience the race finally gave. Thanks for the help all.